# Open serial (COM1) line on Linux to manage a switch through the console

Tags: console, serial

I have connected a switch to a PC with a serial cable, and I want to manage it. What utility can I use to open a serial line and manage the switch through the console?

On Windows I used [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) (serial line COM1).

Comment: For the record, there is Putty on Linux too. At least on Debian since Wheezy (7).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Minicom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom). Look [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/connect-soekris-single-board-computer-using-minicom.html) for some tutorial.

Comment: I'm using gpsfeed+, and set serial parameetrs to COM1 & 4800. I couldn't get data via 'minicom -c on'; It says 'cannot open /dev/ttyS0: No such file or directory'. minicom serial port setup as /dev/ttyS0, 4800 8N1. What's wrong?

Comment: Does /dev/ttyS0 actually exist? If you're using a USB to serial adapter (which might be COM1 on Windows if you don't have a physical serial port), you'll probably have to use `/dev/ttyUSB0` or something similar (exact name might depend on kernel and chipset of adapter).

Answer (score 6):

GNU Screen will do this as well.  You just provide the argument of whatever device you are using, for example:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0
screen /dev/ttyS0
```

Like any other file, you will need read write privileges for the /dev/tty* devices. See the 'Window Types' section of `man screen` to see how to specify the baud rate etc, but screen can usually figure this out.

Comment: screen is the hassle free way

Answer (score 3):

I prefer [picocom](http://freshmeat.net/projects/picocom/) personally.

Minicom has too much ncurses bloat for my liking. It always takes me ages to get where I want.

Whereas with picocom you specify all of your options (baud/parity/stop) on the command line, no fuss.

Comment: You can easily set a minirc.dfl file in /etc/, a ~/.minirc.dfl or whatever, or you can have a script and call it via -s, so it can be automated to a degree.

Comment: I know, it's just far more complicated than it needs to be though. Especially when I find myself changing parity between different hosts.

Answer (score 3):

We use [Kermit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_(protocol)) with a simple configuration/script file that sets the options.

Answer (score 0):

I use minicom.  Relatively straightforward, and works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

I use [CuteCom](http://cutecom.sourceforge.net/) with a USB-to-serial device. You may have to start it with 'sudo ./cutecom' in order to have it access the ttyUSB of your computer.

Comment: Suggesting to use `sudo` to get around a permissions problem is a very bad idea. in general you never want to use sudo for something that does not actually need admin privileges (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). Users needing to access a serial port don't need them, simply put the user in the `dialout` group, change the udev rules for serial ports so another group is used for them, or temporarily adjust them with a `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyS0` (but this is only a temporary fix and might allow other users to use the port when they're not supposed to)